# Error in parsing csvgrep filters

Tags: bash, csv, associative-array

I've made an associative array in a bash script like

```
declare -A file
file[a.b.c]="--json --filter '{\"filter \" : \"value \"}'"
```

Trying to execute

```
for i in "${!file[@]}"; do
   csvgrep $i ${file[$i]}
 done
```

and I get error message

```
Error: [csvgrep/0] Unable to parse filters
```

Filters are working fine out of script. Any ideas?

Comment: Quotes aren't processed after expanding variables.

Comment: So, what can I do?

Comment: You should use an array instead of a string containing quotes. But since bash doesn't have arrays of arrays, you'll need to use `eval`.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of where/how could `eval` be used in the code?

Comment: `eval "csvgrep $i ${file[$i]}"`

Comment: If you search SO for `[bash] eval quotes` you'll find a number of other questions that show how to use it.

Comment: Works,thanks a lot

Comment: Any other ideas, please? eval is not acceptable

Comment: I've reopened since the array solution in the other question won't work with the 2-dimensional array. I'm not sure there's anything better than `eval`.